# Event delays for a Monogame project

Tags: c#, gui, monogame

I am making a GUI for my C# Monogame project. So since this was the first time I ever made a GUI that is not winforms-based I took a wrong approach in making it and thus I decided to change it entirely. But now the behavior is not the same.

**TitleScreenOld.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Abducted.GUIElements;
using Abducted.Helpers;

namespace Abducted.GameScreens
{
    public class TitleScreenOld : GameScreen
    {
        string[] menuTxt;
        ButtonGUI[] buttons;
        WindowGUI[] windows;
        CheckBoxGUI[] checkBoxes;
        WindowGUI playWindow, achieveWindow, optionsWindow, exitPromptBox;

        public TitleScreenOld() { }

        public override void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            base.LoadContent(Content);

            if (tempMPBtn == null) tempMPBtn = Content.Load<Texture2D>(MainGame.TempObjPath + @"0") as Texture2D;

            xPos = 50;

            if (menuTxt == null)
            {
                menuTxt = new string[18];
                menuTxt[0] = "";

                menuTxt[1] = @"Version 1.0-alpha";
                menuTxt[2] = @"Copyright (C) 2016 PowerUser Studios";

                menuTxt[3] = @"Play Game";
                menuTxt[4] = @"Choose a game mode";
                menuTxt[5] = @"Single Player";
                menuTxt[6] = @"Multi Player";

                menuTxt[7] = @"Achievements";
                menuTxt[8] = @"Your Achievements";

                menuTxt[9] = @"Settings";
                menuTxt[10] = @"Game Settings";
                menuTxt[11] = @"Display FPS";
                menuTxt[12] = @"Enable Sound";

                menuTxt[13] = @"Exit Game";
                menuTxt[14] = @"Confirm?";
                menuTxt[15] = @"OK";
                menuTxt[16] = @"Cancel";
            }

            if (buttons == null)
            {
                buttons = new ButtonGUI[9];
                // Unused Dummy Button
                buttons[0] = new ButtonGUI(false, new Rectangle((int)MainGame.DefaultPos.X, (int)MainGame.DefaultPos.Y, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.Y), MainGame.EmptyString, new Rectangle((int)MainGame.DefaultPos.X, (int)MainGame.DefaultPos.Y, (int)MainGame.DefaultPos.X, (int)MainGame.DefaultPos.Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, MainGame.NoTint, Content);

                // Real Buttons
                buttons[1] = new ButtonGUI(false, new Rectangle(xPos, 310, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.Y), menuTxt[3], new Rectangle(101, 328, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[3]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[3]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, MainGame.NoTint, Content);
                buttons[2] = new ButtonGUI(false, new Rectangle(xPos, 390, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.Y), menuTxt[7], new Rectangle(73, 411, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[7]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[7]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, MainGame.NoTint, Content);
                buttons[3] = new ButtonGUI(false, new Rectangle(xPos, 470, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.Y), menuTxt[9], new Rectangle(120, 488, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[9]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[9]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, MainGame.NoTint, Content);
                buttons[4] = new ButtonGUI(false, new Rectangle(xPos, 550, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.Y), menuTxt[13], new Rectangle(106, 571, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[13]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[13]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, MainGame.NoTint, Content);
                buttons[5] = new ButtonGUI(false, new Rectangle(550, 199, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.Y), menuTxt[5], new Rectangle(580, 217, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[5]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[5]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, MainGame.NoTint, Content);
                buttons[6] = new ButtonGUI(true, new Rectangle(550, 279, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.Y), menuTxt[6], new Rectangle(588, 297, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[6]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[6]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, MainGame.DisabledColor, Content);
                buttons[7] = new ButtonGUI(false, new Rectangle(548, 362, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.Y), menuTxt[15], new Rectangle(659, 382, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[15]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[15]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, MainGame.BadColor, Content);
                buttons[8] = new ButtonGUI(false, new Rectangle(548, 442, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUI.btnSize.Y), menuTxt[16], new Rectangle(629, 462, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[16]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[16]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, MainGame.NoTint, Content);
            }

            windowPos = new Vector2(516.0f, 84.0f);
            if (windows == null)
            {
                windows = new WindowGUI[4];
                windows[0] = playWindow = new WindowGUI(windowPos, menuTxt[4], new Vector2(748.0f, 147.0f), true, Content);
                windows[1] = achieveWindow = new WindowGUI(windowPos, menuTxt[8], new Vector2(763.0f, 147.0f), true, Content);
                windows[2] = optionsWindow = new WindowGUI(windowPos, menuTxt[10], new Vector2(801.0f, 147.0f), true, Content);
                windows[3] = exitPromptBox = new WindowGUI(new Vector2(521.0f, 222.0f), menuTxt[14], new Vector2(610.0f, 249.0f), false, Content);
            }

            if (checkBoxes == null)
            {
                checkBoxes = new CheckBoxGUI[2];
                checkBoxes[0] = new CheckBoxGUI(false, false, new Rectangle(800, 200, 16, 16), MainGame.GameFontSmall, MainGame.NoTint, menuTxt[11], content);
                checkBoxes[1] = new CheckBoxGUI(true, true, new Rectangle(800, 300, 16, 16), MainGame.GameFontSmall, MainGame.NoTint, menuTxt[12], content);
            }

            if (MainGame.IsFPSEnabled) checkBoxes[0].IsChecked = true;
            else checkBoxes[0].IsChecked = false;
            checkBoxes[0].Click += new EventHandler(CheckBox0_Click);
        }

        public override void UnloadContent()
        {
            if (tempMPBtn != null) tempMPBtn = null;
            if (menuTxt != null) menuTxt = null;

            foreach (ButtonGUI btn in buttons) btn.UnloadContent();
            foreach (WindowGUI win in windows) win.UnloadContent();
            foreach (CheckBoxGUI checkBox in checkBoxes) checkBox.UnloadContent();

            base.UnloadContent();
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            base.Update(gameTime);

            foreach (ButtonGUI btn in buttons) if (btn != buttons[6]) btn.Update();
            foreach (WindowGUI win in windows) win.Update();

            if ((!playWindow.IsOpen) && (!achieveWindow.IsOpen) && (!optionsWindow.IsOpen) && (!exitPromptBox.IsOpen)) for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) CheckBtnInputTS(buttons[i]);

            CheckWinInputTS(playWindow, buttons[5], buttons[6]);
            CheckWinInputTS(achieveWindow, null);
            CheckWinInputTS(optionsWindow, null);
            CheckWinInputTS(exitPromptBox, buttons[7], buttons[8]);

            CheckBoxInputTS(optionsWindow, gameTime, checkBoxes[0]);
        }

        public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) buttons[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
            foreach (WindowGUI win in windows) win.Draw(spriteBatch);

            if (playWindow.IsOpen)
            {
                buttons[5].Draw(spriteBatch);
                // buttons[6].Draw(spriteBatch);
                // Dirty hack until the button bugs are fixed.
                spriteBatch.Draw(tempMPBtn, new Vector2(550.0f, 279.0f), MainGame.NoTint);
            }
            if (achieveWindow.IsOpen)
            {
                // TODO: Draw stuff
            }
            if (optionsWindow.IsOpen)
            {
                checkBoxes[0].Draw(spriteBatch);
                checkBoxes[1].Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            if (exitPromptBox.IsOpen)
            {
                buttons[7].Draw(spriteBatch);
                buttons[8].Draw(spriteBatch);
            }

            base.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        public void CheckBtnInputTS(ButtonGUI btn)
        {
            if (MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(btn.texRect)) if ((!btn.IsHeld) || (!btn.IsDisabled)) btn.IsHovered = true;
            if (!btn.IsDisabled)
            {
                if (MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(btn.texRect))
                {
                    btn.IsHovered = true;
                    if (btn == buttons[7]) btn.Color = Color.Red;
                    else btn.Color = MainGame.HoverColor;

                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftClicked())
                    {
                        if (btn == buttons[1])
                        {
                            playWindow.IsOpen = true;
                            achieveWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            optionsWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = false;
                        }
                        if (btn == buttons[2])
                        {
                            achieveWindow.IsOpen = true;
                            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            optionsWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = false;
                        }

                        if (btn == buttons[3])
                        {
                            optionsWindow.IsOpen = true;
                            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            achieveWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = false;
                        }
                        if (btn == buttons[4])
                        {
                            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = true;
                            optionsWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            achieveWindow.IsOpen = false;
                        }
                        if (btn == buttons[5])
                        {
                            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            StopSong();
                            MainGame.ScreenManager.AddScreen(new CharacterScreen());
                        }
                        if (btn == buttons[6])
                        {
                            // TODO
                        }
                        if (btn == buttons[7])
                        {
                            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = false;
                            optionsWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            achieveWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            MainGame.ClassExit = true;
                        }
                        if (btn == buttons[8])
                        {
                            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = false;
                            optionsWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
                            achieveWindow.IsOpen = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftHeld()) if (btn == buttons[1]) btn.IsHeld = true;
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftHeld()) if (btn == buttons[2]) btn.IsHeld = true;
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftHeld()) if (btn == buttons[3]) btn.IsHeld = true;
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftHeld()) if (btn == buttons[4]) btn.IsHeld = true;
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftHeld()) if (btn == buttons[5]) btn.IsHeld = true;
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftHeld()) if (btn == buttons[6]) btn.IsHeld = true;
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftHeld()) if (btn == buttons[7]) btn.IsHeld = true;
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftHeld()) if (btn == buttons[8]) btn.IsHeld = true;
                    if (!exitPromptBox.IsOpen) buttons[8].IsHeld = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    btn.IsHovered = false;
                    btn.IsHeld = false;
                    btn.Color = MainGame.NoTint;
                }
            }
            else btn.Color = MainGame.DisabledColor;

            if (MainGame.InputManager.IsKeyPressed(Keys.F1))
            {
                if ((!achieveWindow.IsOpen) && (!optionsWindow.IsOpen) && (!exitPromptBox.IsOpen))
                {
                    playWindow.IsOpen = true;
                }
            }
            if (MainGame.InputManager.IsKeyPressed(Keys.F2))
            {
                if ((!playWindow.IsOpen) && (!optionsWindow.IsOpen) && (!exitPromptBox.IsOpen))
                {
                    achieveWindow.IsOpen = true;
                }
            }
            if (MainGame.InputManager.IsKeyPressed(Keys.F3))
            {
                if ((!playWindow.IsOpen) && (!achieveWindow.IsOpen) && (!exitPromptBox.IsOpen))
                {
                    optionsWindow.IsOpen = true;
                }
            }
            if (MainGame.InputManager.IsKeyPressed(Keys.F4))
            {
                if ((!playWindow.IsOpen) && (!achieveWindow.IsOpen) && (!optionsWindow.IsOpen))
                {
                    exitPromptBox.IsOpen = true;
                }
            }
        }

        ///
        /// <summary>
        /// ButtonGUI value can be null not because we are passing the button
        /// that opened the window but the buttons that exist within the window.
        /// The main buttons are already calling CheckBtnInputTs(ButtonGUI btn)
        /// so no need to do that again.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        public void CheckWinInputTS(WindowGUI win, params ButtonGUI[] btn)
        {
            if ((MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(win.ExitRect)) && (win.IsOpen))
            {
                win.IsExitHovered = true;
                if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftClicked()) win.IsOpen = false;

                if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftHeld()) win.IsExitHeld = true;
            }
            else if ((!MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(win.ExitRect)) || (!win.IsOpen))
            {
                win.IsExitHovered = false;
                win.IsExitHeld = false;
            }
            for (int i = 5; i < buttons.Length; i++) if ((btn != null) && (win.IsOpen)) CheckBtnInputTS(buttons[i]);
        }

        public void CheckBoxInputTS(WindowGUI win, GameTime gameTime, params CheckBoxGUI[] cb)
        {
            foreach (CheckBoxGUI checkBox in checkBoxes)
            {
                if (!checkBox.IsDisabled)
                {
                    if ((MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(checkBox.CheckBoxRect)) || (MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(checkBox.CheckBoxTxtRect)) || (MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(checkBox.CheckBoxMiddleRect)))
                    {
                        checkBox.IsHovered = true;
                        checkBox.Update();
                        checkBox.TxtColor = MainGame.HoverColor;
                    }
                    else if ((!MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(checkBox.CheckBoxRect)) || (!win.IsOpen))
                    {
                        checkBox.IsHovered = false;
                        checkBox.TxtColor = MainGame.NoTint;
                    }
                }
                else checkBox.TxtColor = MainGame.DisabledColor;
            }
        }

        private void CheckBox0_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            MainGame.IsFPSEnabled = !MainGame.IsFPSEnabled;
        }
    }
}
```

**ButtonGUIOld.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Abducted.Helpers;

namespace Abducted.GUIElements
{
    public class ButtonGUIOld
    {
        // TODO: Fix disabled buttons still emitting sound upon click.
        static Texture2D btnTex, btnTexHover, btnTexDisabled, btnTexHeld;
        public static Vector2 btnSize;
        SoundEffect clickSFX;
        string BTNTxt { get; set; }
        public bool IsClicked { get; set; }
        public bool IsHovered { get; set; }
        public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
        public bool IsHeld { get; set; }
        public Rectangle BTNRect { get; set; }
        public SpriteFont SpriteFont { get; set; }
        public Color Color { get; set; }
        public Rectangle texRect { get; set; }

        public ButtonGUIOld(bool btnDisabled, Rectangle newTexRect, string newTxt, Rectangle newRect, SpriteFont newSpriteFont, Color newColor, ContentManager content)
        {
            texRect = newTexRect;
            IsDisabled = btnDisabled;
            SpriteFont = newSpriteFont;
            BTNRect = newRect;
            BTNTxt = newTxt;
            Color = newColor;
            if (btnTex == null) btnTex = content.Load<Texture2D>(MainGame.ButtonPath + @"0") as Texture2D;
            if (btnTexHover == null) btnTexHover = content.Load<Texture2D>(MainGame.ButtonPath + @"1") as Texture2D;
            if (btnTexDisabled == null) btnTexDisabled = content.Load<Texture2D>(MainGame.ButtonPath + @"2") as Texture2D;
            if (btnTexHeld == null) btnTexHeld = content.Load<Texture2D>(MainGame.ButtonPath + @"3") as Texture2D;
            if (clickSFX == null) clickSFX = content.Load<SoundEffect>(MainGame.BGSoundPath + @"1") as SoundEffect;
            if (btnTex != null) btnSize = new Vector2(btnTex.Width, btnTex.Height);
        }

        public void UnloadContent()
        {
            if (btnTex != null) btnTex = null;
            if (SpriteFont != null) SpriteFont = null;
            if (BTNRect != MainGame.EmptyRect) BTNRect = MainGame.EmptyRect;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BTNTxt)) BTNTxt = null;
            if (Color != MainGame.SmallColor) Color = MainGame.SmallColor;
            if (btnTexHover != null) btnTexHover = null;
            if (btnTexDisabled != null) btnTexDisabled = null;
            if (btnTexHeld != null) btnTexHeld = null;
            if (clickSFX != null) clickSFX = null;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            if (!MainGame.IsSoundDisabled)
            {
                if ((IsHovered) && (!IsDisabled))
                {
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftClicked())
                    {
                        clickSFX.Play();
                        IsHovered = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            if ((SpriteFont != null) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BTNTxt)))
            {
                if ((btnTex != null) && (btnTexHover != null) && (btnTexHeld != null) && (btnTexDisabled != null))
                {
                    if (IsHeld) spriteBatch.Draw(btnTexHeld, texRect, MainGame.NoTint);
                    else if (IsHovered) spriteBatch.Draw(btnTexHover, texRect, MainGame.NoTint);
                    else if (IsDisabled) spriteBatch.Draw(btnTexDisabled, texRect, MainGame.NoTint);
                    else spriteBatch.Draw(btnTex, texRect, MainGame.NoTint);
                }
                TextOutliner.DrawBorderedText(spriteBatch, SpriteFont, BTNTxt, new Vector2(BTNRect.X, BTNRect.Y), Color);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

From here start the new classes.

**GUIElement.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Abducted.Helpers;

namespace Abducted.GUIElements
{
    public abstract class GUIElement
    {
        protected SpriteFont Font;
        protected string Text;
        protected SoundEffect ClickSFX;
        public Rectangle Bounds, TextRect;
        public Color ForeColor, BackColor;
        public bool IsDisabled, IsHovered, IsClicked, IsHeld;
        public event EventHandler Click;

        public GUIElement(Rectangle newBounds, Rectangle textRect, SpriteFont font, string newTxt, bool isDisabled, ContentManager content)
        {
            Bounds = newBounds;
            TextRect = textRect;
            Text = newTxt;
            IsDisabled = isDisabled;
            Font = font;
            ForeColor = MainGame.NoTint;
            BackColor = MainGame.NoTint;
            ClickSFX = content.Load<SoundEffect>(MainGame.BGSoundPath + @"1") as SoundEffect;
        }

        public virtual void UnloadContent()
        {
            if (Bounds != Rectangle.Empty) Bounds = MainGame.EmptyRect;
            if (TextRect != Rectangle.Empty) TextRect = MainGame.EmptyRect;
            if (Font != null) Font = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text)) Text = null;
            if (ForeColor != MainGame.SmallColor) ForeColor = MainGame.SmallColor;
            if (BackColor != MainGame.SmallColor) BackColor = MainGame.SmallColor;
            if (ClickSFX != null) ClickSFX = null;
        }

        public virtual void Update()
        {
            if (!IsDisabled)
            {
                if (Bounds.Contains(MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect))
                {
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftClicked()) IsClicked = true;
                    ForeColor = MainGame.HoverColor;
                    if (!IsHeld) IsHovered = true;
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftClicked()) if (Click != null) Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftHeld()) IsHeld = true;
                    else IsHeld = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsHovered = false;
                    IsHeld = false;
                    ForeColor = MainGame.NoTint;
                }
            }
            else ForeColor = MainGame.DisabledColor;
        }

        public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            if ((Font != null) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))) TextOutliner.DrawBorderedText(spriteBatch, Font, Text, new Vector2(TextRect.X, TextRect.Y), ForeColor);
        }
    }
}
```

**ButtonGUINew.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Abducted.GUIElements
{
    public class ButtonGUINew : GUIElement
    {
        static Texture2D btnTex, btnTexHover, btnTexDisabled, btnTexHeld;
        public static Vector2 btnSize;
        public Rectangle boundsRect { get; set; }
        public Rectangle txtRect { get; set; }
        string BTNTxt { get; set; }

        public ButtonGUINew(Rectangle boundsRectangle, Rectangle txtRectangle, SpriteFont font, string newTxt, bool isDisabled, ContentManager content)
        : base(boundsRectangle, txtRectangle, font, newTxt, isDisabled, content)
        {
            boundsRect = boundsRectangle;
            BTNTxt = newTxt;
            IsDisabled = isDisabled;
            if (btnTex == null) btnTex = content.Load<Texture2D>(MainGame.ButtonPath + @"0") as Texture2D;
            if (btnTexHover == null) btnTexHover = content.Load<Texture2D>(MainGame.ButtonPath + @"1") as Texture2D;
            if (btnTexDisabled == null) btnTexDisabled = content.Load<Texture2D>(MainGame.ButtonPath + @"2") as Texture2D;
            if (btnTexHeld == null) btnTexHeld = content.Load<Texture2D>(MainGame.ButtonPath + @"3") as Texture2D;
            if (btnTex != null) btnSize = new Vector2(btnTex.Width, btnTex.Height);
        }

        public override void UnloadContent()
        {
            base.UnloadContent();
            if (btnTex != null) btnTex = null;
            if (boundsRect != MainGame.EmptyRect) boundsRect = MainGame.EmptyRect;
            if (txtRect != MainGame.EmptyRect) txtRect = MainGame.EmptyRect;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BTNTxt)) BTNTxt = null;
            if (btnTexHover != null) btnTexHover = null;
            if (btnTexDisabled != null) btnTexDisabled = null;
            if (btnTexHeld != null) btnTexHeld = null;
        }

        public override void Update()
        {
            base.Update();
        }

        public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            if ((btnTex != null) && (btnTexHover != null) && (btnTexHeld != null) && (btnTexDisabled != null))
            {
                if (IsHeld) spriteBatch.Draw(btnTexHeld, boundsRect, MainGame.NoTint);
                else if (IsHovered) spriteBatch.Draw(btnTexHover, boundsRect, MainGame.NoTint);
                else if (IsDisabled) spriteBatch.Draw(btnTexDisabled, boundsRect, MainGame.NoTint);
                else spriteBatch.Draw(btnTex, boundsRect, MainGame.NoTint);
            }

            base.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }
}
```

**TitleScreenNew.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Abducted.GUIElements;
using Abducted.Helpers;

namespace Abducted.GameScreens
{
    public class TitleScreenNew : GameScreen
    {
        string[] menuTxt;
        ButtonGUINew[] buttons;
        WindowGUI[] windows;
        WindowGUI playWindow, achieveWindow, optionsWindow, exitPromptBox;

        public TitleScreenNew() { }

        public override void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            base.LoadContent(Content);

            if (tempMPBtn == null) tempMPBtn = Content.Load<Texture2D>(MainGame.TempObjPath + @"0") as Texture2D;

            xPos = 50;

            if (menuTxt == null)
            {
                menuTxt = new string[18];
                menuTxt[0] = "";

                menuTxt[1] = @"Version 1.0-alpha";
                menuTxt[2] = @"Copyright (C) 2016 PowerUser Studios";

                menuTxt[3] = @"Play Game";
                menuTxt[4] = @"Choose a game mode";
                menuTxt[5] = @"Single Player";
                menuTxt[6] = @"Multi Player";

                menuTxt[7] = @"Achievements";
                menuTxt[8] = @"Your Achievements";

                menuTxt[9] = @"Settings";
                menuTxt[10] = @"Game Settings";
                menuTxt[11] = @"Display FPS";
                menuTxt[12] = @"Enable Sound";

                menuTxt[13] = @"Exit Game";
                menuTxt[14] = @"Confirm?";
                menuTxt[15] = @"OK";
                menuTxt[16] = @"Cancel";
            }

            if (buttons == null)
            {
                buttons = new ButtonGUINew[9];
                // Unused Dummy Button
                buttons[0] = new ButtonGUINew(new Rectangle((int)MainGame.DefaultPos.X, (int)MainGame.DefaultPos.Y, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.Y), new Rectangle((int)MainGame.DefaultPos.X, (int)MainGame.DefaultPos.Y, (int)MainGame.DefaultPos.X, (int)MainGame.DefaultPos.Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, MainGame.EmptyString, false, Content);

                // Real Buttons
                buttons[1] = new ButtonGUINew(new Rectangle(xPos, 310, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.Y), new Rectangle(101, 328, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[3]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[3]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, menuTxt[3], false, Content);
                buttons[2] = new ButtonGUINew(new Rectangle(xPos, 390, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.Y), new Rectangle(73, 411, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[7]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[7]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, menuTxt[7], false, Content);
                buttons[3] = new ButtonGUINew(new Rectangle(xPos, 470, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.Y), new Rectangle(120, 488, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[9]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[9]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, menuTxt[9], false, Content);
                buttons[4] = new ButtonGUINew(new Rectangle(xPos, 550, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.Y), new Rectangle(106, 571, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[13]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[13]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, menuTxt[13], false, Content);
                buttons[5] = new ButtonGUINew(new Rectangle(550, 199, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.Y), new Rectangle(580, 217, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[5]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[5]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, menuTxt[5], false, Content);
                buttons[6] = new ButtonGUINew(new Rectangle(550, 279, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.Y), new Rectangle(588, 297, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[6]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[6]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, menuTxt[6], true, Content);
                buttons[7] = new ButtonGUINew(new Rectangle(548, 362, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.Y), new Rectangle(659, 382, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[15]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[15]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, menuTxt[15], false, Content);
                buttons[8] = new ButtonGUINew(new Rectangle(548, 442, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.X, (int)ButtonGUINew.btnSize.Y), new Rectangle(629, 462, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[16]).X, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuTxt[16]).Y), MainGame.GameFontLarge, menuTxt[16], false, Content);
            }

            windowPos = new Vector2(516.0f, 84.0f);
            if (windows == null)
            {
                windows = new WindowGUI[4];
                windows[0] = playWindow = new WindowGUI(windowPos, menuTxt[4], new Vector2(748.0f, 147.0f), true, Content);
                windows[1] = achieveWindow = new WindowGUI(windowPos, menuTxt[8], new Vector2(763.0f, 147.0f), true, Content);
                windows[2] = optionsWindow = new WindowGUI(windowPos, menuTxt[10], new Vector2(801.0f, 147.0f), true, Content);
                windows[3] = exitPromptBox = new WindowGUI(new Vector2(521.0f, 222.0f), menuTxt[14], new Vector2(610.0f, 249.0f), false, Content);
            }

            if (checkBoxes == null)
            {
                checkBoxes = new CheckBoxGUI[2];
                checkBoxes[0] = new CheckBoxGUI(false, false, new Rectangle(800, 200, 16, 16), MainGame.GameFontSmall, MainGame.NoTint, menuTxt[11], content);
                checkBoxes[1] = new CheckBoxGUI(true, true, new Rectangle(800, 300, 16, 16), MainGame.GameFontSmall, MainGame.NoTint, menuTxt[12], content);
            }

            if (MainGame.IsFPSEnabled) checkBoxes[0].IsChecked = true;
            else checkBoxes[0].IsChecked = false;
            checkBoxes[0].Click += new EventHandler(CheckBox0_Click);
        }

        public override void UnloadContent()
        {
            if (tempMPBtn != null) tempMPBtn = null;
            if (menuTxt != null) menuTxt = null;

            foreach (ButtonGUINew btn in buttons) btn.UnloadContent();
            foreach (WindowGUI win in windows) win.UnloadContent();
            foreach (CheckBoxGUI checkBox in checkBoxes) checkBox.UnloadContent();

            base.UnloadContent();
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            base.Update(gameTime);

            foreach (WindowGUI win in windows) win.Update();

            if ((!playWindow.IsOpen) && (!achieveWindow.IsOpen) && (!optionsWindow.IsOpen) && (!exitPromptBox.IsOpen))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    buttons[i].Update();
                    buttons[i].IsHeld = false;
                }
                buttons[1].Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
                buttons[2].Click += new EventHandler(Button2_Click);
                buttons[3].Click += new EventHandler(Button3_Click);
                buttons[4].Click += new EventHandler(Button4_Click);
            }
            else
            {
                if (playWindow.IsOpen) buttons[1].IsHeld = true;
                if (achieveWindow.IsOpen) buttons[2].IsHeld = true;
                if (optionsWindow.IsOpen) buttons[3].IsHeld = true;
                if (exitPromptBox.IsOpen) buttons[4].IsHeld = true;
            }

            if (playWindow.IsOpen)
            {
                buttons[5].Update();
                buttons[6].Update();
                buttons[5].Click += new EventHandler(Button5_Click);
                buttons[6].Click += new EventHandler(Button6_Click);
            }
            if (exitPromptBox.IsOpen)
            {
                buttons[7].Update();
                buttons[8].Update();
                buttons[7].Click += new EventHandler(Button7_Click);
                buttons[8].Click += new EventHandler(Button8_Click);
            }

            if (MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(buttons[7].Bounds)) buttons[7].ForeColor = Color.Red;

            if (MainGame.InputManager.IsKeyPressed(Keys.F1))
            {
                if ((!achieveWindow.IsOpen) && (!optionsWindow.IsOpen) && (!exitPromptBox.IsOpen))
                {
                    playWindow.IsOpen = true;
                }
            }
            if (MainGame.InputManager.IsKeyPressed(Keys.F2))
            {
                if ((!playWindow.IsOpen) && (!optionsWindow.IsOpen) && (!exitPromptBox.IsOpen))
                {
                    achieveWindow.IsOpen = true;
                }
            }
            if (MainGame.InputManager.IsKeyPressed(Keys.F3))
            {
                if ((!playWindow.IsOpen) && (!achieveWindow.IsOpen) && (!exitPromptBox.IsOpen))
                {
                    optionsWindow.IsOpen = true;
                }
            }
            if (MainGame.InputManager.IsKeyPressed(Keys.F4))
            {
                if ((!playWindow.IsOpen) && (!achieveWindow.IsOpen) && (!optionsWindow.IsOpen))
                {
                    exitPromptBox.IsOpen = true;
                }
            }

            CheckWinInputTS(playWindow);
            CheckWinInputTS(achieveWindow);
            CheckWinInputTS(optionsWindow);
            CheckWinInputTS(exitPromptBox);

            CheckBoxInputTS(optionsWindow, gameTime, checkBoxes[0]);
        }

        public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) buttons[i].Draw(spriteBatch);

            foreach (WindowGUI win in windows) win.Draw(spriteBatch);

            if (playWindow.IsOpen)
            {
                buttons[5].Draw(spriteBatch);
                // buttons[6].Draw(spriteBatch);
                // Dirty hack until the button bugs are fixed.
                spriteBatch.Draw(tempMPBtn, new Vector2(550.0f, 279.0f), MainGame.NoTint);
            }
            if (achieveWindow.IsOpen)
            {
                // TODO: Draw stuff
            }
            if (optionsWindow.IsOpen)
            {
                checkBoxes[0].Draw(spriteBatch);
                checkBoxes[1].Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            if (exitPromptBox.IsOpen)
            {
                buttons[7].Draw(spriteBatch);
                buttons[8].Draw(spriteBatch);
            }

            base.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
        public void CheckWinInputTS(WindowGUI win)
        {
            if ((MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(win.ExitRect)) && (win.IsOpen))
            {
                win.IsExitHovered = true;
                if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftClicked()) win.IsOpen = false;

                if (MainGame.InputManager.IsLeftHeld()) win.IsExitHeld = true;
            }
            else if ((!MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(win.ExitRect)) || (!win.IsOpen))
            {
                win.IsExitHovered = false;
                win.IsExitHeld = false;
            }
        }

        public void CheckBoxInputTS(WindowGUI win, GameTime gameTime, params CheckBoxGUI[] cb)
        {
            foreach (CheckBoxGUI checkBox in checkBoxes)
            {
                if (!checkBox.IsDisabled)
                {
                    if ((MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(checkBox.CheckBoxRect)) || (MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(checkBox.CheckBoxTxtRect)) || (MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(checkBox.CheckBoxMiddleRect)))
                    {
                        checkBox.IsHovered = true;
                        checkBox.Update();
                        checkBox.TxtColor = MainGame.HoverColor;
                    }
                    else if ((!MainGame.InputManager.MouseRect.Intersects(checkBox.CheckBoxRect)) || (!win.IsOpen))
                    {
                        checkBox.IsHovered = false;
                        checkBox.TxtColor = MainGame.NoTint;
                    }
                }
                else checkBox.TxtColor = MainGame.DisabledColor;
            }
        }

        private void ClearBtn()
        {
            foreach (ButtonGUINew btn in buttons)
            {
                btn.ForeColor = MainGame.NoTint;
                btn.IsHovered = false;
                btn.IsHeld = false;
            }
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            playWindow.IsOpen = true;
            achieveWindow.IsOpen = false;
            optionsWindow.IsOpen = false;
            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = false;
        }
        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            achieveWindow.IsOpen = true;
            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
            optionsWindow.IsOpen = false;
            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = false;
        }
        private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            optionsWindow.IsOpen = true;
            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
            achieveWindow.IsOpen = false;
            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = false;
        }

        private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = true;
            optionsWindow.IsOpen = false;
            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
            achieveWindow.IsOpen = false;
        }

        private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            ClearBtn();
            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
            StopSong();
            MainGame.ScreenManager.AddScreen(new CharacterScreen());
        }

        private void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            // TODO
            // ClearBtn();
        }

        private void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            ClearBtn();
            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = false;
            optionsWindow.IsOpen = false;
            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
            achieveWindow.IsOpen = false;
            MainGame.ClassExit = true;
        }

        private void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            exitPromptBox.IsOpen = false;
            optionsWindow.IsOpen = false;
            playWindow.IsOpen = false;
            achieveWindow.IsOpen = false;
            ClearBtn();
        }

        private void CheckBox0_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            MainGame.IsFPSEnabled = !MainGame.IsFPSEnabled;
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I click on a `ButtonGUI` it while the left mouse button is held the `ButtonGUI` also has `IsHeld = true`.

Now the old behavior was:

1. I click on a `ButtonGUI`.
2. The specified `WindowGUI` opens.
3. `ButtonGUI` has `IsHeld = true` while window is open and `false` when I close it.

Current code behavior:

1. I click on a `ButtonGUI`.
2. The specified `WindowGUI` opens. Good so far...
3. But now `ButtonGUI` has `IsHeld = false` while window is open. So I was forced to do the dirty hacks that exist in TitleScreenNew.cs just to make it look the way I want it to.

Is this caused because firing events has delay? It would make sense as when I click the `ButtonGUI` it still has the same behavior but the `WindowGUI` opens with delay and the `ButtonGUI` no longer has `IsHeld = true` since the mouse was released.

**InputManager.cs**

```
public bool IsLeftClicked()
{
    if ((PrevMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) && (CurrMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)) return true;
    PrevMouseState = CurrMouseState;
    return false;
}

public bool IsLeftHeld()
{
    if ((PrevMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) && (CurrMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)) return true;
    PrevMouseState = CurrMouseState;
    return false;
}
```

I'd like someone to analyze this for me. I don't want to be forced to keep these hacks in my `TitleScreen` class.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I think your code does work, I just want to clarify: does your code work, or is it broken?

Comment: It works! What I am concerned about is a visual issue. When `ButtonGUI.IsHeld = true` the button texture changes as you can see in both `ButtonGUI` classes in `Draw()`  method.

Comment: Is that intended? Because, if not and you are asking for help for how to fix that problem, then this post is off-topic.

Comment: The old behavior as I described it in the question body is intended. The new one, however is not. I just made a bunch of workarounds to make it look the same. And I'm not happy with that.

Comment: So can you help me out @SirPython ?

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with C# to help.

Comment: I just debugged my code and found the problem. It was a wrong `IsHeld` declaration in `Update()`. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Okay, I'm still very confused. If your code has this weird behavior that you are still trying to fix, this post is off-topic. Period.

Comment: What I meant was, I did a mistake in the `Update()` method for the new version of the code. That's why it was doing weird things. Now I fixed it. Such a relief...

Comment: Alright, please fix up your post and your code now.